# Where do I find the turrets practicing singing in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I read in [this question's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20534/carolines-fate/20627#20627)
that you can see the singing turrets of the Portal 2 ending practicing earlier in the game.

Where can I find them?

Comment: @Billare: The end scene is one of the biggest spoilers, please keep it out of the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can watch some of the turrets practicing their singing from a vent in Test Chamber 16:

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look at them now in my game :)

Answer (score 4):

You can see the soprano turret in the elevator after the first hard light bridge level — chamber 11 in chapter 3.

[image: Here it is.]